# Where can I run my Expo app with custom native code?

Tags: android, ios, react-native, expo, eas

**Problem Overview**

I'm been developing an app in Expo for the past couple months with no problem whilst using Expo Go as my method of visualising the app in a UI.

I've since reach a point in which I need to deviate from this development approach as I require to make use of the following modules (as they're not compatible with Expo Go):

- `react-native-google-mobile-ads` *(For displaying Admob Ads)*
- `@react-native-google-signin/google-signin` *(For allowing users to sign into Google in Splash page)*

**What I've found**

I'm evaluating my options but am finding it difficult to determine a suitable solution. Some of the options I have found so far are:

- `expo eject` -  I don't want to have to manage and develop each Platform independently.
- `eas build` - Using the EAS system can take 2+ hours to run this command or it's very expense to use the premium service.
- `eas build --local` -  Running on Windows It's not compatible with this OS (only macos and linux)

**Question**

Apologies I am new to app development but have I missed something or is there a more viable solution to this that I have missed?

Comment: Avoid ```expo eject```,  ```eas build``` would let you build your own development client together with config plugin.